# where is gst_bin_dispose function called when movie ends abnormal?

Tags: gstreamer

when movie is ended abnormally in pause state(in case of Streame error), 
gst_bin_dispose function is not called.

where is gst_bin_dispose function called? and why is this function not called?

Answer (score 0):

gst_bin_dispose function is called whenever the bin is destroyed. That means when the refcount of the GObject reaches 0 which implies the object is destructed.

Full documentation at: https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#GObjectClass.dispose